Linux sed with < and >
I want to replace all the entries of below string in a xml file
<level>error</level>

with
<level>debug</level>

Tried various option with sed, nothing to help. Could someone help?

Share waht you tried

I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Just use the substitute command:
sed -e 's,<level>error</level>,<level>debug</level>,g'


Probably this needs to be your sed expression. The trick is that the < and > chars needs to be escaped with a backslash.
sed s/\>error\</\>debug\</

Example for processing a file named input.xml and transforming it into `output.xml
sed s/\>error\</\>debug\</ input.xml > output.xml

And if you want to be fully precise, I think the forward slash needs to be escaped by two backslashes
sed s/\<level\>error\<\\/level\>/\<level\>debug\<\\/level\>/


or sed 's/>error</>debug</'
